# Can I pipe a dataset into two functions without calling the dataset twice?

Tags: r, magrittr

In `R`, suppose I have a dataset and I want to run the functions `str()` and `summary()`.

In base `R`, I would do this.

```
summary(data)
str(data)
```

If I am using `magrittr` or the whole `tidyverse` suite, I prefer to do this.

```
data %>% str()
data %>% summary()
```

But then, I have to say `data` twice, which I don't like. Now of course,

```
data %>%
str() %>%
summary()
```

does not work because that's not how the pipe works.

Is there a way I can use some operators or functions so that I only have to call `data` once?

Comment: You can use `data %>% {print(str()); summary()}`

Comment: @akrun I really like this solution as well as the accepted answer. I can't accept this since it's a comment but wanted to thank you for point that out!

Comment: It's okay.  Gregor's solution is better suited for you as you are already using `magrittr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `magrittr` "Tee pipe"

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %T>%
  str %>%
  summary
```

If you're interested in "advanced" piping, take a look at the documentation. The [`magrittr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) shows examples of `%T>%`, `%$%`, `%<>%`, and other convenience functions for dedicated pipers.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd rather keep your results :

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  map(lst(nrow, ncol), ~.(.y), .)
#> $nrow
#> [1] 32
#> 
#> $ncol
#> [1] 11
```